# HTML line spacing

Tags: html, format, neat

This is a problem I have had for a long time and although it seems like a small thing my ocd will never let it go.

the basic question has to do with the HTML code itself. Is it at possible to have a line of code go onto a new line but still have it read in as though it were on a single line.

for example

```
<div id="content">
   <img src="www.this_link_url_is_way_too_goddamn_long_to_be_one_one_goddamn_line_so_it_needs_to_be_split_onto_two_goddamn_lines.com"/>
</div>
```

into

```
<div id="content">
   <img src="www.this_link_url_is_way_too_goddamn
   long_to_be_one_one_goddamn_line_so_it_needs
   _to_be_split_onto_two_goddamn_lines.com"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Answer (score 2):

No. Whitespace, in this context, is significant.

Try using an editor that will word wrap lines.

[image: Example of an editor that word wraps]

(This is Sublime Text 2, other editors are available).

Comment: That was the answer I was afraid of, I'm happy with my current editor (notepad++). Thanks a bunch though

Answer (score 0):

This mostly depends on your window size and screen resolution.
And your text editor as well.